# Проброс события из библиотеки C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, события

Пишу простое приложение для захвата видеопотока с IPкамеры на винформах используя фреймворк AForge. Что бы код не был свалкой, вынес многие вещи в отдельную библиотеку, в том числе и захват видеопотока от камеры. 
Создал в классе библиотеки делегат и событие:

```
public event ImageWithDetectionChangedEventHandler CameraImageChanged;
public delegate void ImageWithDetectionChangedEventHandler(object sender, Bitmap img);
```

Так же метод для захвата:

```
public void CreateMjpegVideoStream(string url)
{        
    // Создаем MJPEG видео ресурс с удаленной камеры
    MJPEGStream stream = new MJPEGStream(url);
    // set event handlers
    stream.NewFrame += Video_NewFrame;
    stream.Start();
}
```

В этом методе подписался на событие:

```
private void Video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    _bitmap = eventArgs.Frame; 
}
```

А вот как пробросить изменения уже в форму?
Вот так хочу запустить поток

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _videoMaker.CreateMjpegVideoStream(tbEnteredUrl.Text);
    _videoMaker.CameraImageChanged += CameraServiceCameraImageChanged;
}
```

и здесь изменять содержимое PictureBox:

```
private void CameraServiceCameraImageChanged(object sender, Bitmap img)
{
    pbCameraStream.Image = img;
}
```

И чувствую, что поплыл, и не могу понять как это дело организовать. Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: Так а в чем вопрос вообще? Видно подписки на события, непонятно где эти события триггерятся, непонятно как это должно связываться и что должно происходить

Comment: В примерах `stream.NewFrame += Video_NewFrame;` вызывается непосредственно в коде формы. Тут просто, в реализацию Video_NewFrame() вставляешь `myPictureBox.Image = img;` Сразу же изображение появляется. А мне получается надо из другого класса изменения перенести в класс формы.

Comment: @JDo делаешь последовательный проброс по всем слоям если у тебя нет прямой ссылки на класс библиотеки.

Comment: @JDo так тут два разных события, где они триггерятся? Они связанны между собой вообще?

Comment: Прошу помочь их стриггерить... Потому что делаю что-то не правильно.

Comment: Просто вызови в нужный моменты `CameraImageChanged` и `NewFrame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вы имели ввиду получить доступ к контролу из другого потока? Установить ему **Image** можно так.

```
private void CameraServiceCameraImageChanged(object sender, Bitmap img)
{
var SetImage = new Action(() => { pbCameraStream.Image = img; });
            if (pbCameraStream.InvokeRequired)
                pbCameraStream.Invoke(SetImage);
            else
                SetImage();    
}
```